# How do I find a question which was deleted?

Tags: feature-request

I have an old question related to Lewis Carol's Jabberwocky poem which was deleted -- for containing apparent nonsense -- but I like it so I'd like to view it again. Is there a feature which would allow me to search out the deleted post; which I should still be able to view myself -- so I can look it over, as I still like it, and I would like to show my friends off-site.

When attempting to access site.stackexchange.com to find information on how to do this (as suggested in the comments), I get the following error:

[image: Error Message Shown]

Comment: There is no way to search for arbitrary deleted content. If you have a link to the post (eg from before it was deleted) and your rep is 10K or more, you can view the content. Alternatively, if the post is *yours* and it was deleted recently (not sure what that means but I'd be surprised if it meant more than a month), you can find a link to it in your profile.

Comment: Where abouts on my profile can I find the link to my deleted post?

Comment: See [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile) and the earlier feature-request the sole answer links to.

Comment: No, that URL is a template: <site> is, in the case of EL&U, *english*. Maybe it's easier or more convenient to navigate to the list using the links provided in your profile? Use the screenshots in the question I linked to above to locate the links.

Comment: Found it at: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320003/when-is-a-vorpal-sword-not-a-vorpal-sword

Comment: Oh, well done. It was deleted only seven days ago. Definitely off topic on this site though. Try science fiction on SE http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you authored the post, as your question seems to suggest, you may be able to find it in the questions listed on your own profile. I'm not completely certain of this, though.

Comment: Yeah. The option seems to be appearing now.